# How can I use faker in conjunction with Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, faker

I've been trying to use the faker library to generate data without having it in my test cases as static data.

I have tried calling `fake.md5(raw_output=False)` directly from my keyword and also by creating a variable and assigning it this value, but neither has the intended effect. It seems that no matter what I do, the only output I'm getting during my test is `fake.md5(raw_output=False)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: My keyword (it writes to a specific field, this is just a test keyword to make sure I can use faker) -

```
Write username
    ${md5}=    MD 5
    ${my data}=    log    md5: ${md5}
    Input Text    a11y-username    ${my data}
```

Edit #2 - I realized I had missed out the `log` keyword, I have updated my code

Comment: You seem to have completely changed what you're asking. First it was an issue with how to use faker, now you're asking about the error `object type of 'NoneType' has no len()`? There's no code in your question that is trying to use a `len` function. If you're facing a different problem, please ask in a separate question rather than change this question.

Comment: I have removed the error code, it was the error for mispelled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
${my data}=    md5: ${md5}
```

Robot expects the first cell (or the first cell after a variable name) to be a keyword. So, in this case it thinks `md5: ${md5}` is a keyword, which it obviously is not. That is why you get the error `No keyword with name 'md5: ${md5}' found.`

I don't know what you're expecting to do with that line of code. Your value is already in a variable, are you trying to copy it to another variable, or simply print it out?

If your intention was to log the value, use the [Log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) keyword:

```
Write username
    ${md5}=    MD 5
    log  md5: ${md5}
```

If you instead want to copy the value to another variable, you can use the [Set Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) keyword:

```
write username
    ${md5}=  MD 5
    ${my data}=  set variable  ${md5}
    Input Text  a11y-username  ${my data}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I have to use my phone to comment unfortunately. My workplace blocks external JavaScript.